# rails- Pass infomation to a controller based on url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller for "Productions" and if you go to `localhost/productions` you see an index page, you can click show and view the show page for that particular productions.
Each production has a unique ID like `036ea872f9011a7c`, I want my users to be able to add items to a production like follows:

```
localhost/productions/036ea872f9011a7c/fixtures/add
localhost/productions/036ea872f9011a7c/positions/add
localhost/productions/036ea872f9011a7c/dimmers/add
localhost/productions/036ea872f9011a7c/channels/add
localhost/productions/036ea872f9011a7c/etc/add
```

Comment: Did you read the [Rails Guide about Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)? It's all in there.

Comment: You can use the unique id in urls automatically by defining the `to_param` method in the model to return the unique id instead of the database id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build a route with the necessary parameters like this:

Suppose we have tasks that we assign to a project

model project.rb:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, through: :project_task
end
```

model task.rb

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects, through: :project_task
end
```

routes.rb

```
...
resources :projects do
  member do
    get 'affect_task/:task_id', action: 'affect_task', as: :affect_task                                     
  end
end
```

projects/show.haml

```
= link_to "task_name", affect_task_project_path(task_id: @task_id, project_id: @project_id)
```

controller.rb

```
...
def affect_task
...
  CollaboratorTask.create(task_id: params[:task_id], project_id: params[:project_id])      
...
end
...
```

Of course this is an example so you understand..